# Python: compute average of n-th elements in list of lists with different lengths

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, nan

Suppose I have the following list of lists:

```
a = [ 
      [1, 2, 3],
      [2, 3, 4],
      [3, 4, 5, 6] 
    ]
```

I want to have the average of each n-th element in the arrays. However, when wanting to do this in a simple way, Python generated out-of-bounds errors because of the different lengths. I solved this by giving each array the length of the longest array, and filling the missing values with None.

Unfortunately, doing this made it impossible to compute an average, so I converted the arrays into masked arrays. The code shown below works, but it seems rather cumbersome.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

a = [ [1, 2, 3],
      [2, 3, 4],
      [3, 4, 5, 6] ]

# Determine the length of the longest list
lenlist = []
for i in a:
    lenlist.append(len(i))
max = np.amax(lenlist)

# Fill each list up with None's until required length is reached
for i in a:
    if len(i) <= max:
        for j in range(max - len(i)):
            i.append(None)

# Fill temp_array up with the n-th element
# and add it to temp_array 
temp_list = []
masked_arrays = []
for j in range(max):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        temp_list.append(a[i][j])
    masked_arrays.append(ma.masked_values(temp_list, None))
    del temp_list[:]

# Compute the average of each array 
avg_array = []
for i in masked_arrays:
    avg_array.append(np.ma.average(i))

print avg_array
```

Is there a way to do this more quickly? The final list of lists will contain 600000 'rows' and up to 100 'columns', so efficiency is quite important :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[tertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) would do all the padding with None's for you so your code can be reduced to:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from itertools import izip_longest

a = [ [1, 2, 3],
      [2, 3, 4],
      [3, 4, 5, 6] ]


averages = [np.ma.average(ma.masked_values(temp_list, None)) for temp_list in izip_longest(*a)]

print(averages)
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0]
```

No idea what the fastest way in regard to the numpy logic but this is definitely going to be a lot more efficient than your own code.

If you wanted a faster pure python solution:

```
from itertools import izip_longest, imap

a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [2, 3, 4],
     [3, 4, 5, 6]]


def avg(x):
    x = filter(None, x)
    return sum(x, 0.0) / len(x)


filt = imap(avg, izip_longest(*a))

print(list(filt))
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0]
```

If you have 0's in the arrays that won't work as 0 will be treated as Falsey, you will have to use a list comp to filter in that case but it will still be faster:

```
def avg(x):
    x = [i for i in x if i is not None]
    return sum(x, 0.0) / len(x)

filt = imap(avg, izip_longest(*a))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just a FYI, `izip_longest` was renamed to `zip_longest` in Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an almost* fully vectorized solution based on [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) and [`np.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) -

```
# Store lengths of each list and their cumulative and entire summations
lens = np.array([len(i) for i in a]) # Only loop to get lengths
C = lens.cumsum()
N = lens.sum()

# Create ID array such that the first element of each list is 0, 
# the second element as 1 and so on. This is needed in such a format
# for use with bincount later on.
shifts_arr = np.ones(N,dtype=int)
shifts_arr[C[:-1]] = -lens[:-1]+1
id_arr = shifts_arr.cumsum()-1

# Use bincount to get the summations and thus the 
# averages across all lists based on their positions. 
avg_out = np.bincount(id_arr,np.concatenate(a))/np.bincount(id_arr)
```

-* Almost because we are getting the lengths of lists with a loop, but with minimal computation involved there, must not affect the total runtime hugely.

Sample run -

```
In [109]: a = [ [1, 2, 3],
     ...:       [2, 3, 4],
     ...:       [3, 4, 5, 6] ]

In [110]: lens = np.array([len(i) for i in a])
     ...: C = lens.cumsum()
     ...: N = lens.sum()
     ...: 
     ...: shifts_arr = np.ones(N,dtype=int)
     ...: shifts_arr[C[:-1]] = -lens[:-1]+1
     ...: id_arr = shifts_arr.cumsum()-1
     ...: 
     ...: avg_out = np.bincount(id_arr,np.concatenate(a))/np.bincount(id_arr)
     ...: 

In [111]: avg_out
Out[111]: array([ 2.,  3.,  4.,  6.])
```

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion this is the fastest :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well I am hoping so! :D Still would depend on the data format OP has.

Answer (score 3):

You can already clean your code to compute the max length: this single line does the job:

```
len(max(a,key=len))
```

Combining with other answer you will get the result like so:

```
[np.mean([x[i] for x in a if len(x) > i]) for i in range(len(max(a,key=len)))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also avoid the `masked array` and use `np.nan` instead:

```
def replaceNoneTypes(x):
    return tuple(np.nan if isinstance(y, type(None)) else y for y in x)

a = [np.nanmean(replaceNoneTypes(temp_list)) for temp_list in zip_longest(*df[column], fillvalue=np.nan)]
```

Answer (score 1):

On your test array:

```
[np.mean([x[i] for x in a if len(x) > i]) for i in range(4)]
```

returns

```
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python version >= 3.4, then import the statistics module

```
from statistics import mean
```

if using lower versions, create a function to calculate mean

```
def mean(array):
    sum = 0
    if (not(type(array) == list)):
        print("there is some bad format in your input")
    else:
        for elements in array:
            try:
                sum = sum + float(elements)
            except:
                print("non numerical entry found")
        average = (sum + 0.0) / len(array)
        return average
```

Create a list of lists, for example

```
myList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10],[11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22],[23]]
```

iterate through myList

```
for i, lists in enumerate(myList):
    print(i, mean(lists))
```

This will print down the sequence n, and the average of nth list.

To find particularly the average of only nth list, create a function

```
def mean_nth(array, n):
    if((type(n) == int) and n >= 1 and type(array) == list):
        return mean(myList[n-1])
    else:
        print("there is some bad format of your input")
```

Note that index starts from zero, so for instance if you are looking for the mean of 5th list, it will be at index 4. this explains n-1 in the code.

And then call the function, for example

```
avg_5thList = mean_nth(myList, 5)
print(avg_5thList)
```

Running the above code on myList yields following result:

```
0 2.0
1 6.0
2 9.5
3 12.5
4 18.5
5 23.0
18.5
```

where the first six lines are generated from the iterative loop, and display the index of nth list and list average. Last line (18.5) displays the average of 5th list as a result of `mean_nth(myList, 5)` call.

Further, for a list like yours,

```
a = [ 
      [1, 2, 3],
      [2, 3, 4],
      [3, 4, 5, 6] 
    ]
```

Lets say you want average of 1st elements, i.e. (1+2+3)/3 = 2, or 2nd elements, i.e., (2+3+4)/3 = 3, or 4th elements such as 6/1 = 6, you will need to find the length of each list so that you can identify in the nth element exists in a list or not. For that, you first need to arrange your list of lists in the order of length of lists.

You can either

1) first sort the main list according to size of constituent lists iteratively, and then go through the sorted list to identify if the constituent lists are of sufficient length

2) or you can iteratively look into the original list for length of constituent lists.

(I can definitely get back with working out a faster recursive algorithm if needed)

Computationally second one is more efficient, so assuming that your 5th element means 4th in the index(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), or nth element means (n-1)th element, lets go with that and create a function

```
def find_nth_average(array, n):
    if(not(type(n) == int and (int(n) >= 1))):
        return "Bad input format for n"
    else:
        if (not(type(array) == list)):
            return "Bad input format for main list"
        else:           
            total = 0
            count = 0
            for i, elements in enumerate(array):
                if(not(type(elements) == list)):
                    return("non list constituent found at location " + str(i+1))                
                else:
                    listLen = len(elements)
                    if(int(listLen) >= n):
                        try:
                            total = total + elements[n-1]
                            count = count + 1
                        except:
                            return ("non numerical entity found in constituent list " + str(i+1))
            if(int(count) == 0):
                return "No such n-element exists"
            else:
                average = float(total)/float(count)
                return average
```

Now lets call this function on your list `a`

```
print(find_nth_average(a, 0))
print(find_nth_average(a, 1))
print(find_nth_average(a, 2))
print(find_nth_average(a, 3))
print(find_nth_average(a, 4))
print(find_nth_average(a, 5))
print(find_nth_average(a, 'q'))
print(find_nth_average(a, 2.3))
print(find_nth_average(5, 5))
```

The corresponding results are:

```
Bad input format for n
2.0
3.0
4.0
6.0
No such n-element exists
Bad input format for n
Bad input format for n
Bad input format for main list
```

If you have an erratic list, like

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], 2, [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

that contains a non - list element, you get an output:

```
non list constituent found at location 2
```

If your constituent list is erratic, like:

```
a = [[1, 'p', 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

that contains a non - numerical entity in a list, and find the average of 2nd elements by `print(find_nth_average(a, 2))`

you get an output:

```
non numerical entity found in constituent list 1
```

Comment: I dont understand whoever has downvoted it, why just did it without leaving any comment with the reasoning!!

Comment: Not mine but maybe if you try running your code you will see why